# How to set X-Forwarded-For in Node.Js app while calling with axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios, x-forwarded-for

Okay, I just got an opportunity to work in nodejs, where I am using `axios` library to fetch the data from third party url.

Everything was working very smoothly until it was deployed to staging ENV.

Similar issue I got while working with rails, and the solution I found was to use

`@request['X-Forwarded-For'] = 'XX.YYY.Z.Z'` in header.

Coming to the issue now, have already tried

`options = { headers: { 'X-Forwarded-For': 'XX.YYY.Z.Z' } }` and its not working at all even at local env :/

`axios.get(URL, options);`
This is how I am using it to fetch the data, but it keeps loading and loading,

Is there anything I am missing or alternative of it so that I can try that instead?

Comment: Hiii there, you are not getting data using axios.get(URL).then().catch() right? and what you are getting error from server side?

Comment: Hello @PrakashKarena , I am getting data from it, but it seems like the requested page is restricting my proxy to fetch the data, (same proxy is able to access while calling the api from rails) and in response, it says "We're temporarily unavailable, will server you shortly" indicates its sending unauthorised request's response to me.
Please let me know if I made it clear enough to explain you, else I'll add more data to describe the issue.

Comment: I think you might be getting CORs(cross-origin) error by your browser right?

Comment: @PrakashKarena Yes it seems so, any solution to avoid this thing and get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

use this middleware after creation of app from express

```
 //CORS error solution 
    app.use((req,res,next)=>{
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:3000');//your frontend origin 
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type ,Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization');
        next();
    })
```

Hope this will help you. if you have any query then let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I am getting the response with 200 status, its the output which is not correct, without the X-Forwarded-For header, I am getting the json response which is right at its place, but when I add this header, then I get a whole HTML page which says they're currently offline, with that I am assuming they do not want to share data with my call :/ and its only at the staging, its super fine at the local.