# Response difference on local and EC2 server when hitting request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, server, request, local

Okay so I did not get anything from my last [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58688647/how-to-set-x-forwarded-for-in-node-js-app-while-calling-with-axios) may be I was not so clear in detailing the issue I am facing, so hoping this time I'll get solution for my issue:

```
var request = require("request");
var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/web/AAPStoresWithAvailableInventoryCmd',
  qs: 
   { quantity: '1',
     partNumber: '2130015-P',
     storeId: '10151',
     catalogId: '10051',
     langId: '-1',
     loadStoresComponent: 'true',
     latitude: '',
     longitude: '',
     prefStoreNickName: '8511' },
  headers: 
   { accept: 'application/json, text/plain, /',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36',
     'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
     origin: 'https://shop.advanceautoparts.com' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

I am getting accurate data about what I need when I try this at local ENV.
BUT when the same code is executed at my EC2 server, I get an awkward response from the code above.

**RESPONSE AT LOCAL**

```
{
"loadStoresComponent": ["true"],
"langId": ["-1"],
"quantity": ["1"],
"prefStoreNickName": ["8511"],
"latitude": [""],
"longitude": [""],
"authToken": "-1002%2C3a0VN%2Bt240MbliDjfWLSDJxolLA%3D",
"catalogId": ["10051"],
"DM_PersistentCookieCreated": ["true"],
"partNumber": ["2130015-P"],
"storeId": ["10151"],
"Result": {
"view": "availableStoresList",
"storesListMap": [
{
"inStock": true,
"state": "NC",
"isPrefStore": false,
"distance": 0,
"storeBrand": "AAP",
"city": "MATTHEWS",
"latitude": "35.137527",
"address1": "9507 INDEPENDENCE BLVD.",
"zipCode": "281050000",
"nickName": "8511",
"phone": "704-845-5004",
"longitude": "-80.715079"
},
{
"inStock": true,
"state": "NC",
"isPrefStore": false,
"distance": 4,
.....
.....
}
```

**RESPONSE AT SERVER**

```
<div class="pagewidth">
  <div class="logo">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="tagline">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="header">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="heading">We're offline for a tune-up, we'll be up and  running smoothly very soon. </p>
    <p class="heading">In the meantime, here are some other options available:</p>
    <div class="section group">
      <div class="col span_1_of_4"> Visit an <br />
        <strong>Advance Auto Parts store</strong><br />
        <a href="http://stores.advanceautoparts.com/"><img src="/MaintPage/images/DM150205_maintenance_page_07.png" width="200" height="125" border="0" /></a> </div>
      <div class="col span_3_of_4"> Sign up for <br />
        <strong>SpeedPerks Rewards</strong><br />
        <a href="http://www.speedperks.com"><img src="/MaintPage/images/sp-logo.png" width="204" height="100" border="0" style="margin-top:20px;" /></a> </div>
      <div class="col span_4_of_4"> View us on Social Media <strong><br />
        Facebook/Twitter/Blog</strong><br />
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/advanceautoparts"><img src="/MaintPage/images/DM150205_maintenance_page_12.png" width="110" height="125" border="0" /></a><a href="https://twitter.com/AdvanceAuto"><img src="/MaintPage/images/DM150205_maintenance_page_16.png" width="92" height="125" border="0" /></a><a href="http://blog.advanceautoparts.com/"><img src="/MaintPage/images/button-m.png" width="90" height="125" border="0" style="margin-left:0px;" /></a> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    <p class="heading">We appreciate your patience – on your next visit, <strong>use coupon code PS20 for 20% off your purchase. </strong></p>
    <p class="coupon"><img src="/MaintPage/images/DM150205_maintenance_page_21.png" width="354" height="134" /></p>
    <p style="margin:30px; text-align:center;">We look forward to serving you,<br />
      The Advance Team</p>
    <p style="margin:30px; text-align:center;">&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically it is an offline page(didn't paste whole HTML body and CSS), by which I feel that they are denying to return the response of my request.

I have tried adding `x-forwarded-for` in my call as well but no luck with that.
And I am getting an accurate response by adding `x-forwarded-for` in rails, but I guess there may be some extra headers or anything else I need to add in my request to get the desired result.

Any thoughts on my issue?

Comment: Please make sure you enter the correct url (https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/web/AAPStoresWithAvailableInventoryCmd) without any typo in EC2 server. I dont force any other issues in the code.

Comment: https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/web/AAPStoresWithAvailableInventoryCmd?quantity=1&partNumber=2130015-P&storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&langId=-1&loadStoresComponent=true&latitude=&longitude=&prefStoreNickName=8511

This is the actual URL.
I used postman for nodejs code snippet for that request code.

Comment: Am curious to know, how you are running this code in your EC2 instance. Are you using the above shared postman code snippet for execution or executing it in some other ways. I can able to get the above mentioned error page by creating typo error in URL. Just giving you a hint to debug this issue. URL with typo: (AAPStoresWithAvailableInventoryCmd as AAPStoresWithAvailableIentoryCmd )https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/web/AAPStoresWithAvailableIentoryCmd?quantity=1&partNumber=2130015-P&storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&langId=-1&loadStoresComponent=true&latitude=&longitude=&prefStoreNickName=8511

Comment: With the typo mistake, it returns `We were unable to process your request. Please try again` but in my scenario it is displaying `We're offline for a tune-up, we'll be up and  running smoothly very soon.`  Sorry, I am newbie to nodejs, and by running this code in my EC2 instance, I meant, I did `node` at my staging server (for opening console I assume or maybe), and pasted the code, hope I made it clear this time.